# Parsing and extracting JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm using Google geocoding API and trying to get the value: 
**9.081999, and 
8.675276999999999** respectively in the the following Google geocoding JSON data in Javascript.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Nigeria",
               "short_name" : "NG",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Nigeria",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 13.8856449,
                  "lng" : 14.677982
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 4.2464428,
                  "lng" : 2.676932
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 9.081999,
               "lng" : 8.675276999999999
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 13.8856449,
                  "lng" : 14.677982
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 4.2464428,
                  "lng" : 2.676932
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJDY2kfa8LThARyAvFaEH-qJk",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

But when I do this:

```
var myJSONResult = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
var myAddress = Array();
for (i = 0; i < myJSONResult.results.length; i++) {
        myAddress[i] = myJSONResult.results[i].geometry.location;
}
```

It returns `Undefined`

Any help is appreciated, 
Thanks.

Comment: `results[i]` is already `geometry`

Comment: Even at that, `results[i]` still gives `Undefined`

Comment: why are you using $.parseJSON()? Just try 
var myJSONResult = request.responseText

Comment: @Yogesh request.responseText contains the whole JSON data and I need only the value in `"location" : {
               "lat" : 9.081999,
               "lng" : 8.675276999999999
            }`

Comment: try replacing 
    var myJSONResult = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
with 
    var myJSONResult = request.responseText;

Comment: Your script *is working* so the error must be somewhere else: https://jsfiddle.net/d1Lg6ysp/

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Never mind, I got it working with this: `var myJSONResult = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
     for (i = 0; i < myJSONResult.results.length; i++) {

      $('#map_canvas').gmap3({
       marker:{
        address: ''+myJSONResult.results[i].geometry.location.lat+','+myJSONResult.results[i].geometry.location.lng 
       },
       map:{
        options:{
         zoom: 10,
         scrollwheel: false,
         streetViewControl : true
        }
       }
      });
     }`.  Thanks for your time, though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var myJSONResult = request.responseText;
var myAddress = Array();
for (i = 0; i < myJSONResult.results.length; i++) {
        myAddress[i] = myJSONResult.results[i].geometry.location;
}
```

No need of using `$.parseJSON()`, since your response is already a JSON object.